# What is a good portable for screenshot or capture?

Tags: windows, gratis, usb, portable

What I would like to get a good screenshot or screen capture for a portable ?

- Prefer that it be just for screen only.
- Don't want an image editor.
- Prefer it be freeware or gratis

The one I use the most on my workstation Microsoft OneNote 2013 but I would like to have it similiar to it ?

Does anyone in here have any suggest of one ?

Comment: So, you want the software to directly save the image somewhere? Without asking you for a name? Triggered by what? Please answer these questions in the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for you would be **ShareX**.

- It is free and open-source.
- It has both Screenshot and Screen Capture capabilities (which is rare to see in one application).
- Is available as a portable program without installation.

While it does have a Image Editor and much more, you aren't forced to use it...so just use it without the editor or all the additional tools.

You can download the portable version here: https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/releases/tag/v11.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Try [Greenshot](https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot/releases).
It's completely free and open source.
And it's very lite, only 1.3MB zipped.

Answer (score -1):

FastStone Capture is absolutely the best screenshot software. And i think there is a Portable version of FSCapture.
http://www.faststone.org/FSCapturerDownload.htm

Comment: Right, you can find the portable on their site http://www.faststone.org/FSCapturerDownload.htm. But it is not free, only a free trial.

Comment: ShareX has FastStone beat hands down.  I just tried the trial version, and it pales in comparison.

Comment: Why is it the best? What makes it recommendable? How does it meet the requirements? Where to find it? Sorry, but this post lacks essential details to be an answer. Currently it's rather a comment. Could you please [edit] it and fill the gaps?